# Prove in elementary set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hi I have question in set theory.
I have a function
f: A$\rightarrow$B  and D$\subset$B.
Now I need to prove this:
1. $D$ $\subset$ $f(f^-1(D))$
2. $f(f^-1(D))$ $\subset$ $D$
Thanks

Comment: The first one is false.

Comment: @Wojowu can you explain why?

Comment: Consider this example: $A=B=D=\mathbb Z$ and $f$ which maps every integer to zero. Then the preimage $f^{-1}(D)$ is whole $\mathbb Z$, but $f(f^{-1}(D))$ only contains zero, so the inclusion doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample to 1: Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ given by $f(n) = 1$. Then $f \circ f^{-1}(\{5\}) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, but $\{5\}$ is not a subset of $\emptyset$.

Comment: Or simply $f:\varnothing\to\{5\}$, the empty map.