# Tao Analysis I - Exercise 3.4.2 on "inverse images"

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I wanted to check my solution to Exercise 3.4.2 from Terence Tao's Analysis I 4th Edition.

The reason is that (1) at least two solution websites give conflicting answers, and (2) the other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4710429/tao-analysis-1-exercise-3-4-2) on this site has an unclear answer.

---

**Exercise 3.4.2**

Let$ f:X \to Y$ be a function from one set X to another set $Y$, let $S$ be a subset of $X$, and let $U$ be a subset of $Y$.

(i) What, in general, can one say about $f^{-1}( f (S))$ and $S$?

(ii) What about $f ( f^{-1}(U))$ and $U$?

(iii) What about $f^{-1}( f ( f^{-1}(U)))$ and $f^{−1}(U)$?

---

**My solutions**

**(i) What, in general, can one say about $f^{-1}( f (S))$ and $S$?**

Since $f$ is defined as a function from $X$ to $Y$, and since $S \subseteq X$, then $f(S)$ is defined, and is a subset of $Y$.

Now, by Definition 3.4.5, $f^{-1}(f(S))$ is the inverse image of $f(S)$ where

$$f^{-1}(f(S)) = \{x \in X: f(x) \in f(S)\}$$

If $x \in S$, then $f(x) \in f(S)$. This means such $x$ belong in the set $\{x \in X: f(x) \in f(S)\}$, which is $f^{-1}(f(S))$.

So we can say $S \subseteq f^{-1}( f (S))$. $\square$

Note, we can't say $f^{-1}( f (S)) \subseteq S$, and so we can't say the two sets are equal.

---

**(ii) What about $f ( f^{-1}(U))$ and $U$?**

This one is easier. By Definition 3.4.5, $f^{-1}(U)$ is the inverse image of $U$ where

$$f^{-1}(U) = \{x \in X: f(x) \in U\}$$

That is, every $x \in f^{-1}(U)$ maps to $U$ under $f$. So if we apply $f$ to this particular set of $x$, we get what the definition tells us, $U$.

$$f(f^{-1}(U)) = U$$

We have shown $f ( f^{-1}(U))$ and $U$ are equal. $\square$

---

**(iii) What about $f^{-1}( f ( f^{-1}(U)))$ and $f ^{−1}(U)$?**

We saw in (ii) above that $f(f^{-1}(U)) = U$, and so substituting gives us

$f^{-1}( f ( f^{-1}(U))) = f^{-1}(U)$

The two sets are the same. $\square$

---

**Request**

I am self-teaching which is difficult for me with no access to a mentor or teacher. I would appreciate replies which are not cryptic, if it all possible.

Comment: $f(f^{-1}(U)) \subseteq U$, not $=$ generally ($U$ may contain elements without an antecedent).

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is a function, and $U\subseteq Y$, then is not true, in general, that $f(f^{-1}(U))=U$. Try thinking of an example of a function $f$ where there is a $y\in Y$ does not lie in the range of $f$. Consider the case $U=\{y\}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove in elementary set theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022770/prove-in-elementary-set-theory)

Comment: I'm still struggling, sorry. So let me explain my thinking step by step. By definition $f^{-1}(U)$ are just those $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \in U$. So applying the function $f$ to just those $x$ goes us $U$. 

Are the comments suggesting that image of $f^{-1}(U)$ under $f$ a subset of $U$? This would mean there are $x$ in the $f^{-1}(U)$ which don't map to $U$ which seems to contradict the definition of inverse image.

Comment: @Joe if there is a $y$ not in the range of $f$ then it can't be in $Y$ because $f$ is defined to map $X \to Y$. I can't see the error in my thinking.

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks for trying to help. $U$ may contain elements without an antecedent. But surely $f$ is defined as mapping $X \to Y$ so any element of $Y$ has an antecedent in $X$? And since $U \subseteq U$, so does $U$ ?

Comment: @Penelope: You seem to be assuming that in the notation $f:X\to Y$, every $y\in Y$ lies in the image of $f$. That is, you seem to be assuming that for every $y\in Y$ there must be an $x\in X$ satisfying $f(x)=y$. This is not correct. The notation $Y$ denotes the codomain of $f$.

Comment: In Tao's book, he calls the codomain of $f$ the "range of $f$", but I think this is confusing, because these days, it is more common to use the term "range" to refer to the image of $f$.

Comment: For example, the function $f:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ such that $f(x)=x^2+1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ has the domain $\mathbb R$, the codomain $[0,\infty)$, and the image $[1,\infty)$. Try setting $U=\{1/2\}$ in my above example. You should get that $f^{-1}(U)=\varnothing$. Does that help?

Comment: @Joe - you've found the root of my confusion. I had known, then forgotten, that codomain is not image.

Comment: Again: your post was a duplicate of [these counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2022815/386889).

Comment: Hi @AnneBauval - I see that now but couldn't before because I didn't see the error of my thinking, as pointed out by Joe.

Comment: The 2 short solutions showed it explicitely, though. Anyway, I was just recalling that post to incite people to vote to close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @AnneBauval I would suggest it is not a duplicate as the discussion here has helped unlock a misunderstanding that the other one doesn't. I found several similar questions posted but none helpfully answered or commented. It is beneficial to the community to not be so zealous in closing posts.

Comment: Sorry but I am still convinced that a  look at the linked post would have been as helpful as the discussion here to "unlock your misunderstanding".